# Exporting/Importing Sharepoint Recurrence Column with Powershell

Tags: csv, powershell, sharepoint

I'm trying to export the SharePoint calendar Recurrence column to a CSV file (using powershell) then import the column to a SharePoint calendar. I receive a `<!-- #RENDER FAILED -->` error in the Recurrence field in the item review

I am using this to export:

```powershell
Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name "fRecurrence" -value $listItem['fRecurrence'];
```

And this to import (SP13 Calendar)

```powershell
$item["fRecurrence"] = $row."fRecurrence";
```

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but just in case: [Recurrence display <!-- #RENDER FAILED --> when using lists.asmx UpdateListItems method](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/7c779d99-cf58-42cd-a86e-44e88c40fcd7/recurrence-display-render-failed-when-using-listsasmx-updatelistitems-method)